# React init state array with init function that repeatedly calls setState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to init a state array by calling an init function multiple times in the `useEffect` hook.

```js
// id for new Users
const [id, setId] = useState(0);
// users list
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
```

```js
function createUser() {
  const newUser = {
    id: id,
    name: `User-${id}`,
    creationDate: new Date().toLocaleString("en-uk")
  };
  setUsers(oldUsers => {
    let users = oldUsers.slice();
    users = users.concat(newUser);
    return users;
  });
  setId(oldId => oldId + 1);
}
```

And then trying to create 3 users

```js
useEffect(() => {
  createUser();
  createUser();
  createUser();
}, []);
```

I am expecting 3 users will be created with id=0, 1, 2 and the `id` state is now equals to `3`.

However, the output is

```
User-0 with id=0 was created at 11/04/2022, 15:49:00
User-0 with id=0 was created at 11/04/2022, 15:49:00
User-0 with id=0 was created at 11/04/2022, 15:49:00
```

#### Question

Am I missing something here? What should I do to properly initialise the array?

#### What I thought

My actual init function (`createUser` in this example) consists of some complex logic. A possible workaround I can think of is doing the `createUser` logic inside the `useEffect` hook directly, and call `setId` at the end. But this style yields duplicate codes.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    let _users = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        const newUser = { 
            id: i, 
            name: `User-${i}`, 
            creationDate: new Date().toLocaleString("en-uk")
        };
        _users = _users.concat(newUser);
    }
    setUsers(_users);
    setId(3);
}, [])
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/henryfung3a27/pen/KKZeLLN) here

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `createUser` function 3 times on initial render.
But state is preserved regardless of `createUser` state updation.

A better approach would be passing number of required users to the function.  Modify the `createUser` function as:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    function createUser(users) {
      for (var i = 0; i < users; i++) {
        const newUser = {
          id: i,
          name: `User-${i}`,
          creationDate: new Date().toLocaleString("en-uk")
        };
        setUsers((oldUsers) => [...oldUsers, newUser]);
      }
    }
    createUser(3);
  }, []);
```

[View demo on codepen](https://codepen.io/neeerajtk/pen/LYerwPE)

Comment: It worked! But wouldn't it make a new, with identical logic, `createUser` function, along with the one under the component-level? Like what if I need to create another User on-the-fly via. button click?

Comment: As answered by @rockTheWorld useState useEffect are asynchronous and run in batches. There wont be issue when adding user via button click.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. What I meant was that am I supposed to point the `onClick` callback to the component-level `createUser` function, which has the same logic as the one inside the `useEffect` hook? In this case I am going to have 2 `createUser` functions in my component - one in `useEffect` and one under the component.

Comment: @HenryFung In that case, you should move the function outside. Two functions aren't required.

Answer (score 2):

React hooks like `useState` `useEffect` are asynchronous and run in batches. All three `createUser` run in single batch with id=0;

For running complex flows like this, it is recommended to use `useReducer`
[https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#:~:text=useReducer%20is%20usually%20preferable%20to,dispatch%20down%20instead%20of%20callbacks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#:%7E:text=useReducer%20is%20usually%20preferable%20to,dispatch%20down%20instead%20of%20callbacks).

> useReducer is usually preferable to useState when you have complex
> state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state
> depends on the previous one. useReducer also lets you optimize
> performance for components that trigger deep updates because you can
> pass dispatch down instead of callbacks.

With useReducer, you can implement desired logic with id and users inside.

However, I do recommend using nanoid for unique ids.

Answer (score 1):

`useState` is asynchornous, so that's why whenever you call `setId` 3 times at once under `useEffect`, your `oldId` is always referred to 0. To have a complete fix for your case, we should not call `setId` even though `setUsers` multiple times in one code snippet

```
function createUser(id) {
  const newUser = {
    id: id,
    name: `User-${id}`,
    creationDate: new Date().toLocaleString("en-uk")
  };
  //setUsers(oldUsers => [...oldUsers, newUser]); //should not call it here
  //setId(oldId => oldId + 1); //should not call it here
  return newUser; //return the new user
}

useEffect(() => {
    let newUsers = [];
    let currentId = id; //from your state
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        const newUser = createUser(currentId++);
        newUsers.push(newUser)
    }
    setUsers(oldUsers => [...oldUsers, ...newUsers]); //update current user list
    setId(currentId); //update current user id
}, [])
```

If you have a button to add a new user, you can call it like below

```
const handleAddNewUser = () => {
   const currentId = id;
   const newUser = createUser(currentId++);
   setUsers(oldUsers => [...oldUsers, newUser]);
   setId(currentId); //update current user id
}
```

You can check [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-hermann-og32kf?file=/src/App.js:0-1242)

Answer (score 0):

Use this [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) module for id. Id should be unique so you will recieve them from backend api's. And in your scenario when call create function it will call setUser which rerender the component so id remain 0 because of rerendering